# concatenate cells along 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

```
I'm trying to concatenate de values of 2 cells in each raw, along 2 columns.
If the concatenated value (Temp) is equal to another one (MaxT) some cells to the right are affected by a change of background colour. All values are strings of text.

MaxT = CStr(MaxT)
For i = 5 To 88 
TempT = Sheets("B").Range(Cells(i, 2)).Value & Sheets("B").Range(Cells(i, 5)).Value
If TempT = MaxT Then
Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 36)).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 
End If
Next i
```

I'm getting this error:
Run-Time error 1004
Application-defined or object-defined error

Where is the problem in the code?

Comment: You'll need to post your full code and tell us on which line the error occurs.

Comment: try `Sheets("B").Cells(i, 2).Value & Sheets("B").Cells(i, 5).Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
MaxT = CStr(MaxT)
For i = 5 To 88 
TempT = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 2).Value & Sheets("B").Cells(i, 5).Value
If TempT = MaxT Then
Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 36)).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. The problem was in the use of "Range" in the statement.

Comment: Why did you "split" the Interior.Color part? From the original code it seems it should paint everything in between column 7 and 36. Now it only fills 2 columns. Not sure that is the desired behaviour just pointing that out

Comment: @vba4all: you are right, I have it read wrong. I modified the answer. Thanks for the remark...